# Domino server 7.0.3FP1 Proxy settings with java agent

Tags: java, proxy, lotus-domino

First, this is not the first time I ask a question related to this problem, but now that we have talked with the network admin guys and we know we absolutely HAVE to get through that proxy, I will ask again the question but with further details.

So here is the deal. We have an application built for Lotus Notes. That application needs to talk with a web service that is located outside the network of our client, but nothing can get out of the network without going through a proxy server. Since the Agent is running on the server, we need to tell the server to go through the proxy first. That can be achieved in Java using the System's properties (http.proxyHost, etc). That being said, I set all the properties related to the proxy settings in my Java Agent, and then I try getting the XML file from the web service. What I get is a connection time out exception. So, I was wondering why? We did a network analysis with WireShark, and the application is not trying to go through the proxy. Here is what it STRANGELY does.

1. I built the application and set the proxy host to a dummy address, just for the time I get the real proxy address and my credentials. Let's say proxy.mydomain.com
2. I get my credentials, so I change the proxy config with the real ones, say webproxy.ca.mydomain.net
3. Nothing works, so we restart the Domino server and do a clearcache, thinking it might be related to this
4. We did a network analysis with WireShark and the application queries the DNS for this:

   ```
    proxy.mydomain.com
    proxy.mydomain.com.ca.mydomain.com
    proxy.mydomain.com.eu.mydomain.com
    proxy.mydomain.com.anotherknowdomain.com
   ```

And that goes for a while. BUT, I can see it's still using the dummy address. Where does it get it. It's not in notes.ini, it's not in the server's cache, it's not in my source code, it's not in java.properties, it not in the JVM (since we restarted the machine). Any idea? We're at the end of a project and we need this to work to deliver it and preassure is building!!! I searched the WHOLE WEB!!!

One more thing I would say, when I set my properties in java code, I tryied to print them before to see if it was ok and everything is fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, even though it was a web proxy going through HTTP, the JVM setting sockProxyHost was set and preceds on the other. That was our problem...